# I accidently found that I can use vim in git-bash of windows, but how and where to config the vim to better use?

Tags: vim, git-bash

Also, if it is possible to use *visual studio command prompt* in the git-bash?

Answer (score 4):

The `:scriptnames` command  will tell you the config files (and plugins) that are used.

If you haven't yet created a user configuration `~/.vimrc` file, it is placed in your *home directory*. See `:help vimrc` for details.